# Is there an interactive console for public/uploaded app engine apps?

Tags: google-app-engine

The SDK for google ap engine has an "interactive console"
when running your app locally.
I can't find the equivalent in the dashboard for uploaded apps.
I am using Python 2.7, app_engine sdk 1.70

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually there is a way to have the interactive console for your app.

You would need to add the following lines to you app.yaml file.

```
- url: /_ah/admin.*
  script: google.appengine.ext.admin.application
  login: admin
```

See [this doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Referring_to_the_Python_Library_Directory) for some more details (python 2.5).

Comment: I added the above to my app.yaml file and uploaded it. In running I got an error about thread safe so I set trheadsafe: false  OK no more error messages. Now how to I actually USE the console?

Comment: browse to http://you_app.appspot.com/_ah/admin and there will be a link to the console on the left.

Comment: First the above text to add to the yaml file changed substantially since my previous message. I'm presuming the new text is correct so I'm now using that. After successfully uploading the yaml file, when I go to the above URL I get a 404 Not Found error. I will note that the yaml text login: admin indicates that maybe I should login with 'admin' instead of my regular user name that I upload files with or something???

Comment: Make sure you're not adding this clause after any `/.*` handlers - remember that handlers are evaluated in order.

Comment: To save you and future users time, since 2/3 of you work at Google, how about adding a link to this page under a new "interactive console" phrase on the dashboard? Better still would be to clean the text and show it in-line. Best is just present the tool when clicking on that link. Imagine having to add such obscure code to an obscure file just to get a text editor to allow you to edit text?