# FileNotOpenedError with Cloud storage on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to write to a file in cloud storage from the remote api shell and am seeing the following:

```
s~appid> FILENAME = '/gs/test_bucket/test'

s~appid> writable_file = files.gs.create(FILENAME,
mime_type='application/octet-stream', acl='project-private')

s~appid> with files.open(writable_file, 'a') as f:
          ...     f.write('[]')
          ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotOpenedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/dhruvkaranmehta/Projects/getaround3/tools/g3/shell.pyc in <module>()
      1 with files.open(writable_file, 'a') as f:
----> 2     f.write('[]')
      3

/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/files/file.pyc in
__exit__(self, atype, value, traceback)
    288
    289   def __exit__(self, atype, value, traceback):
--> 290     self.close()
    291
    292   def write(self, data, sequence_key=None):

/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/files/file.pyc in
close(self, finalize)
    282     request.set_filename(self._filename)
    283     request.set_finalize(finalize)
--> 284     self._make_rpc_call_with_retry('Close', request, response)
    285
    286   def __enter__(self):

/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/files/file.pyc in
_make_rpc_call_with_retry(self, method, request, response)
    395   def _make_rpc_call_with_retry(self, method, request, response):
    396     try:
--> 397       _make_call(method, request, response)
    398     except (ApiTemporaryUnavailableError,
FileTemporaryUnavailableError):
    399

/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/files/file.pyc in
_make_call(method, request, response, deadline)
    243     rpc.check_success()
    244   except apiproxy_errors.ApplicationError, e:
--> 245     _raise_app_error(e)
    246
    247

/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/files/file.pyc in
_raise_app_error(e)
    186   elif (e.application_error ==
    187         file_service_pb.FileServiceErrors.FILE_NOT_OPENED):
--> 188     raise FileNotOpenedError()
    189   elif (e.application_error ==
    190         file_service_pb.FileServiceErrors.READ_ONLY):

FileNotOpenedError:
```

This seems weird since the file was just opened. I have also seen another scenario where opening a file in 'a' mode leads to a `FinalizationError`.

Any additional information will be greatly helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, there's a feature request to support the files api from the remote api shell. Could you try the same using the interactive console (See [Is there an interactive console for public/uploaded app engine apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404732/is-there-an-interactive-console-for-public-uploaded-app-engine-apps/11405475#11405475)).

Regarding your second error the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/functions#open) states that:

> You cannot open and write to a file that has already been finalized.

Comment: The part about remote api shell turned out to be true.However the problem at hand ended up being that the acl was being set to public-read-write(I scrubbed it by hand in the post). The acl happens to affect the ability to obtain an Exclusive Lock on the file. If you end up with ExclusiveLockFailedError, try changing the acl.